# Cant update becuse Public key not avaible

Tags: upgrade, repository

I cant even install mysql, in the new password section its bugged and asking me again and again. I tried to y/n with every permuation. I looked in the internet it says its about the expired mysql key, and not signed. How can i fix it ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS